# Google is blocking SRWare Iron from its web store. Is there a way around it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

**System:**

Windows 7

Iron 30.0.1650.0

"based on the free Sourcecode "Chromium" (the google browser)"

**Problem:**

When I access the google chrome webstore I get the following error message:

"Your Chrome version is not supported by the Web Store"

**Question:**

Is there a way around it? Maybe tricking it by sending an alternate User Agent string? I am just not quite sure how one can do that.

Comment: "Maybe tricking it by sending an alternate User Agent string?"  Good thinking, what happened when you tried? Where exactly did you get stuck trying it?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The user said they had no idea how to do it. In fact, I don't think it's possible. After all, it's an unofficial (non-blessed, I suppose) fork.

Comment: @slhck If the OP doesn't know how to change the UA string and wants to try that, then the question should be about that.  Not a vague question looking for a work-around, where they offer their own theories for an answer but don't actually try any of them (and/or don't tell us what they tried).

Comment: Note that the current version of Chrome, as of this moment, appears to be 36.0.1985.125. 30.0.1650 is rather old and may not work with the Web Store even if you use a fake User Agent string.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using a SRWare Iron version which is [over 9 months old](http://www.srware.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7316)? [Latest released version](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_download.php) is `35.0.1900.0`, and the Chrome Web Store loads just fine there. You can fake the `User-Agent` string trough the `--user-agent` [switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but that doesn't guarantee that all the apps will actually work, since you're still using an old version.

Comment: @and31415 thank you that did it (upgrade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Upgrade SRWare Iron to [latest released version](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_download.php).

---

## Workaround

You can fake a newer `User-Agent` string trough the `--user-agent` switch, but that doesn't guarantee that all the apps will actually work: you're still using an old version.

While SRWare Iron is Chromium-based and support those switches, they are not readily applicable. The reason is that what gets launched is a program called `iron.exe`, which acts as a wrapper. To bypass this limitation you need to call the `chrome.exe` application directly:

```
"X:\Path\to\SRWare Iron\chrome.exe" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Iron/35.0.1900.0 Chrome/35.0.1900.0 Safari/537.36"
```

**Note** SRWare Iron is supposed to provide an `User-Agent` tweaking feature through an `UA.ini` file placed in the program folder. It didn't work properly when I tested it, though.

### Further reading

- [Run Chromium with flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)
- [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Thank you for your respectful non-judgmental non-patronizing answer. Yes i'm looking at you @Techie007